# Removing binary zero from a string

Tags: vba

I've had to move a whole directory structure (thousands of directories and files) from the Mac to the PC, but now on the PC for some reason some of the folder names have a character on the end of value binary zero ( a few have this in the middle).  I need to clean this up since it crashes a macro which tries to read these directories.
I've tried the following code in a vba-word macro using the Replace function (as part of a larger program that walks through the directory tree) but the Replace function doesn't seem to catch chr(0) .

```
Set current_folder = fso.GetFolder(source_folder.Path)
current_folder_name = current_folder.Name
cleaned_folder_name = Replace(current_folder_name, Chr(0), " ")
Selection.TypeText "Old directory name: " & current_folder_name
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeText "New directory name: " & cleaned_folder_name
Selection.TypeParagraph
If current_folder_name <> cleaned_folder_name Then
    current_folder.Name = cleaned_folder_name
End If
```

I've also tried:
 cleaned_folder_name = Replace(current_folder_name, Chr(0), " ", 1, -1, vbBinaryCompare)

How I can get the Replace function to replace binary 0 in a string by a blank.

Or does anyone knows a different approach to cleaning up these directory and file names that would work.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: First and foremost, do you want `Chr(0)` to be replaced by a `Space` or `nothing`?  Because you have a space in your `replace()` function right now.

Comment: I'll probably put a test in my program and if Chr(0) at end then nothing else a space.  I'll try your solution and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
Dim OldFolderName As String, NewFolderName As String

OldFolderName = source_folder.Path
If InStr(OldFolderName, Chr(0)) > 0 Then
    'NewFolderName = Application.Clean(OldFolderName) 'Works on some versions
    NewFolderName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(OldFolderName) 'By Gene Skuratovsky
    Name OldFolderName As NewFolderName
End If
```

Edit2: Probably best to use the `Clean()` method.

Comment: I don't think this will work.  cleaned_folder_name = Replace(current_folder_name, Chr(0), " ")
always get executed in my code but the Chr(0) never gets replaced by a space.

Comment: Are you sure that the character is `Chr(0)`?

Comment: Added a bit about `"\0"` in my original answer.

Comment: I copied the folder name in windows explorer and pasted it into a hex editor and the last character in the string was binary zero.

Comment: Forgot all about the `Clean()` method.  It should remove all "non-printable characters" such as binary zero.  Updated my answer with that method.  Edit:  `Application.Clean()` duh.

Comment: Tested `Clean` method and it works for end of string non-printables but it seems to clear everything after the null zero see [MY QUESTION ON THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641324/why-does-application-clean-remove-printable-characters-vba)

Comment: You're right the character is not Chr(0).  When I cut and paste the illegal character becomes Chr(0) and Application.CleanString() removes Chr(0) but not this particular illegal string character. Is there a way to determine the value of this illegal character in the folder name?

Comment: Do you know the location of the character in the string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67645/discussion-between-harry-spier-and-chrismas007).

Answer (score 1):

In my case Replace() and InStr() don't work with Chr(0) (can't see it not displaying any error), but this removal can be done for example this way:

```
If Mid$(str, 1, 1) = Chr$(0) Then str = Mid$(str, 2)
If Mid$(str, Len(str), 1) = Chr$(0) Then str = Left$(str, Len(str) - 1)
```

This is Null removal from ends, for example from `objFile.ExtendedProperty("Dimensions")` value, like "?600 x 400?". Nulls (?) are insterted here in Windows 10 but not in Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom loop function to determine what character you are having issues with:

```
OldFolderName = source_folder.Path
For x = 0 To 255
    If InStr(OldFolderName, Chr(x)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Chr(" & x & ") is found at position " & InStr(OldFolderName, Chr(x))
    EndIf
Next x
```

Comment: I've solved it.  It wasn't binary zero (it became binary zero when pasted into a hex editor).  I assigned the string to a byte array, found out what the illegal char. was and then wrote a macro that assigned the name strings to byte arrays checked for illegal char. and then put in value for blank and re-assigned to string.  Thanks.