# Why does Application.Clean() remove printable characters?

Tags: vba, excel

***Bounty Question:***

While there is an answer which provides a reasonable explanation, I want to determine if the truncation of the string occurs because `Clean()` is a `WorksheetFunction` and the reasoning behind that issue.  Do `WorksheetFunctions` when called by `VBA` pass the string into a "cell" so to speak which truncates at the `null Chr(0)`?

***Original Question:***

Why does `TestIt`'s `Application.Clean` method remove all characters after `Chr(0)` even though they are printable?  `TestIt2` correctly returns 8 characters after doing a replace on `null Chr(0)`.

***Edit:***
Worth noting is that some versions of Excel will require you to write   `Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean()`
to test this error.

*Code*

```
Sub TestIt()
    Dim TryIt As String

    TryIt = "Test" & Chr(0) & "asdf"
    MsgBox Len(TryIt) 'Prints 9
    TryIt = Application.Clean(TryIt)
    MsgBox Len(TryIt) 'Prints 4

End Sub
```

and

```
Sub TestIt2()
    Dim TryIt As String

    TryIt = "Test" & Chr(0) & "asdf"
    MsgBox Len(TryIt) 'Prints 9
    TryIt = Replace(TryIt, Chr(0), "")
    MsgBox Len(TryIt) 'Prints 8

End Sub
```

Comment: I can only speculate that it understands `vbNullChar` as the string terminator, which it often is in the unmanaged world. If you use `Char(1)` instead, it only removes that one character. Not a documented behaviour though.

Comment: Good edit. I was about to blast you because [Application doesn't have a Clean method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198091(v=office.15).aspx).

Comment: @RubberDuck. It does have a `Clean` method. It's just that it is not documented. Other examples are `Debug.Print Application.Pi`

Comment: @SiddharthRout [Debug.Print is documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264286(v=office.15).aspx). Not sure about Pi...

Comment: lol@RubberDuck. Did you really think I was talking about `Debug.Print`?

Comment: I did @SiddharthRout! Am I about to go learn something??

Comment: @RubberDuck `Application` does *allow* a `Pi` method (or any Worksheet function exposed by `WorksheetFunction`), *without the need* to use the `WorksheetFunction` object. See https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/2236

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this appears to be very simple: removing all characters following `chr(0)` is a bug.

`Clean` is designed to JUST remove `chr(0)` as well as other nonprinting characters, as indicated in the VBA language reference:

> The Clean function was designed to remove the first 32 nonprinting characters in the 7-bit ASCII code (values 0 through 31) from text.

`Clean` works as expected for all of the other mentioned `chr()` values EXCEPT `chr(0)` after which it clearly removes all following characters.

If you must work with the null value, some kind of conversion will be necessary. You can get the expected result by doing something like `TryIt = Replace(TryIt, Chr(0), Chr(1))` after which the result works as expected (and as it does for all of the other 31 `chr()` codes that `Clean` was designed to remove):

```
Sub TestIt3()

Dim TryIt As String
Dim iCounter As Integer

For iCounter = 0 To 31
    TryIt = "Test" & Chr(iCounter) & "asdf"
    TryIt = Replace(TryIt, Chr(0), Chr(1))
    Debug.Print "chr(" & iCounter & ")" & "  " & Len(TryIt)
    TryIt = Application.Clean(TryIt)
    Debug.Print "cleaned - chr(" & iCounter & ")" & "  " & Len(TryIt)
Next iCounter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

@Gserg is right in the comments above

Visual Basic **cannot** handle strings terminated by a NULL character. In fact all DLLs terminate strings that way. `Chr(0)` is treated as the terminating character for strings.

Here is the best way to check it.

```
Sub TestIt()
    Dim TryIt As String

    TryIt = "Test" & Chr(0) & "asdf"

    Debug.Print Len(TryIt)
    Debug.Print TryIt

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = TryIt
End Sub
```

This will write just "Test" in cell `A1`

The best way is to handle it like you are doing it. Use `.Replace`. The other alternate (longer) way is to use `INSTR`.

Comment: Why does `Clean()` not look character by character but `Replace()` does?

Comment: It is not the fault of `Clean`. Like I mentioned `Visual Basic cannot handle strings terminated by a NULL character` And that is where the problem arises...

Comment: Visual Basic can and will handle strings with a null terminator. For this purpose Visual Basic uses the BSTR string type that stores the length of the string along with the string data. All dlls that support BSTR will also cope - this includes all OLE Automation libraries. If a truncation occurs on the null terminator, that happens outside of VB. E.g. Excel cannot have the null terminator inside its cell, but that is a different story and is an additional restriction Excel imposes because it feels like it - even though both VB and OLE could handle the null character.

Comment: If VBA can't handle a null terminator with `Clean()` then how does it handle it with `Replace()` and how does it handle the length correctly with `Len()`?

Comment: Just re-read your comment @GSerg... Are you implying that because `Clean()` is a `WorksheetFunction` of Excel that it has more limitations handling the `null` terminator than VBA methods?

Comment: @Chrismas007 No, I am speculating that apparently the Clean function was specifically written to crop on the null character because the programmer thought it was a safer idea, or that the Clean function has a bug because of which it truncates when it shouldn't because the programmer made a mistake. In either case it is not a limitation of the function itself, it would have been perfectly able to not crop on the null character if the programmer had written it that way.