# Range.Replace is always true for Chr(1)

Tags: vba, excel, replace

Right now I'm confused. I was going to create an answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45602265/removing-any-non-specified-characters-from-an-excel-spreadsheet-using-a-macro/45602658#45602658).

By running some tests I noticed that

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace Chr(1), "", xlPart, , True, , False, False
```

completely clears out the sheet. It does make sense for `Chr(42)` which is `*` but why `Chr(1)`?

Does anyone know the reason? Is it some kind of second/hidden placeholder?
(Couldn't find something, but used probably just the wrong search terms)

Comment: Interesting. Must be some non-documented feature.

Comment: Just 1 hour... but it feels like this will end with an bounty... also `[A1].value = "-" & Chr(1) & "-"` looks pretty odd :D

Comment: This is very interesting.  Here is what I found.  `Chr(1)` means a `Start of Heading` and here is the document (https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html) describes all the ASCII control characters. Another government website (https://www.its.bldrdoc.gov/fs-1037/dir-034/_5089.htm) has a better "still confusing" explanation to `Chr(1)`.

Comment: @ian0411 I do know what `chr(1)` is, I am just confused why Excel acts like it would do with the asterisk (placeholder) but not for any of the other non printable characters. It seems that something deep inside the application itself "confuses" Excel. So I'm kind if curious what happens down there. (Still I'm sure that I am not able to understand it for real) :P

Comment: I am as confused as you.  You probably found a monster feature that MS doesn't even know.

Comment: Even more interesting is - Chr(1) - moves the final - over a space, but it isn't selectable... and you can't find and replace Chr(1) without VBA

Comment: I assume that `Chr(1)` is the real placeholder (else it would not be possible to search for "*") but having no way to do exactly that (as far as I know) it might be some "leftover". Still if no "programmer" is stopping here by accident, I doubt that I will get a proper answer. :/

Comment: FYI, though not quite the same problem, it might be of some interest to have a look at Why does Application.Clean remove printable characters? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641324/why-does-application-clean-remove-printable-characters

Comment: `Chr(63)` which is `?`  does the same thing

Comment: @KarthickGunasekaran the `?` is the placeholder for a single char, while `*` is the placeholder for any amount of chars...

Comment: @Dirk Reichel, then why it clean all the characters in a sheet

Comment: @KarthickGunasekaran Because you are looking `xlPart` so all occurrences will be replaced (if replacing "a" with "c" then "aba" becomes "cbc"). This way all strings will be cleared char by char) ;)

Comment: More about `chr(1)` [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/933572-vba-char-1-a.html) and [here](https://www.office-forums.com/threads/what-is-the-character-code-chr-for-graphic-g.1868063/).

Comment: @DirkReichel "looks pretty odd" so do the chars upto 7 when just entered in a cell.

Comment: An interesting case indeed. I've found that when adding multiple instances of Chr(1) to a single cell and then replacing them with a random value, it only replaces once in that cell. Therefor I assume it's not actually looking for that value, but instead replaces any cell that's not empty.

Comment: When inserting multiple instances of Chr(1) into a string and then running replace on it, it does catch all instances. It seems this odd behaviour occurs only when referencing cells directly.

Comment: It throws **Run-time error '9':** *Subscript out of range* to me :/

Comment: Out of curiosity - when you do this, if you save the workbook afterwards does it corrupt in any way when you try and open it again?

Comment: My guess is that excel behaviour is connected with chr(1) interpretaion. Try running: `SendKeys Chr(1)` it works like CTRL+A, `Chr(2)` works like CTRL+B etc. (more details here http://dc.org/files/asciitable.pdf). It may be that vba interprates chr(1) as 'select all' therefore all non-empty cells are replaced.

Comment: @TomJohnRiddle, in fact, Chr(1) (amongst others) is not supported by windows. Your guess it seems is right. Excel's interpretation of Chr(1) will be to select everything. In case of OP it will replace with empty cells. But see what happens when you try to replace with "Hello". This will also work on any other range :)

Comment: I'm not sure about the "select all" part. It does make sense in some way, but replace is a function which will compare 2 strings. If there is "2.0" and you try to replace "0" with something, nothing will happen, but at "2.01" it will do. So numerical values will be converted (ignores number formatting). Simply looking for a number or a string doesn't matter. It simply compares 2 strings. No cell will be selected or text inside of the cells. If this function would "select" something, it would be extremely slow. Also having chr(1) inside a cell does not flip over the effect.

Comment: While `ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(Chr(1), ActiveCell).Activate` also will act like the condition is always met, other compare methods do not show that behavior like `instr()`. And just as a hint: this also works if you open the replace window and paste the `Chr(1)` expression in the search box. And as another "contra" for the "select all": Microsoft Word doesn't show this behavior at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason can be inferred from the difference between

- **NUL** : No character. It is used for filling in time or filling space on the surface (such as surface of platter) of storage device where there are no data. We’ll use this character when we’ll be doing programming for data wipers (destructive and non-destructive both) to wipeout the unallocated space so that deleted data may not be recovered by any one or by any program.
- **SOH** : This character is used to indicate the start of heading, which may contain address or routing information.
- **STX** : This character is used to indicate the start of text and in this way this is also used to indicate the end of the heading.

[Source of Definition](https://www.datadoctor.biz/data_recovery_programming_book_chapter4-page18.html)

---

Various comments have already pointed out that these characters (first 32) are called the control characters because these characters perform various printer and display control operations rather than displaying symbols.

In Hadoop, SOH is often used as field separator especially while reading CSV files. Also, upon opening the Excel file (without unzipping as plain xlsx i.e. as binary) in Notepad++ and printing the control characters, one will see a lot of SOH characters. Due to the security features, one won't be able to see the actual data.

chr(0) = SOH is a pointer to the Memory address of all the cells containing TEXT

and

chr(1) = NUL is a pointer to the Memory address of all the cells containing NULL or BLANK CELLS

Let's look at the above statements in purview to the different commands shown in the image below. The TOP-LEFT is the original data range and example shows that how replacement works for SOH, NUL and ASTERISK (*) using the Range.Replace function.

[image: SOH Replace ALL in EXCEL]

---

So, why Chr(0) & Chr(1) are able to replace the values in the Excel Cell if they are merely address pointers and how chr(1) is acting differently than chr(42)?

This happens because of the structure of an Excel Worksheet. When you open a brand new Excel Workbook, the Excel Cells are not marked. It's completely visually and in hard and soft memory of the system.

However, As soon a one enters something in Cell B2 then all the BLANK CELLS squared upto B2 will be assigned a pointer with Chr(0) and Cell B2 will be assigned a pointer with Chr(1).

Now, if one deletes the content of cell B2 then along with other cells B2 will be assigned a NUL or Chr(0) pointer to it.

This is also the reason that why merely clearing the contents using Cells.ClearContents won't clear the cells in the memory and Excel workbook bloats when a far distant cell was used but not deleted using Cells.Clear or Ctrl+Delete.

---

Now, while it is clear that why Excel replaces the contents or clears the worksheet with the given command. It's also, important to understand the difference between asterisk (*) and SOH [or Chr(0)].

Asterisk (*) replaces the contents of cells with minimum length 0.

While Chr(0) identifies the cells with SOH i.e. the cells containing value and then the replace the value at the destination of pointer.

The difference is not in result but how the cells to be replaced are find or identified.

---

I created a small macro to validate the hypotheses in which I am recording the time it takes to replace half a million cells (A1 to CZ5000) using Chr(1) = SOH and Chr(42) = *

It turns out that using the pointer to address of cells with TEXT i.e. SOH takes less time than ASTERISK (*).

[image: Time taken to replace text]

---

```
Sub Replace_Timer()

    Sheet3.Activate

    Dim startTime, endTime
    Dim i As Integer

        Sheet3.Range("A1:CZ5000").Value = "A"

    For i = 1 To 25
        startTime = Timer
            Sheet3.Cells.Replace Chr(1), "X", xlPart, xlRows, False
        endTime = Timer
        Sheet4.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = endTime - startTime 'Execution time in miliseconds

        startTime = Timer
            Sheet3.Cells.Replace Chr(42), "Z", xlPart, xlRows, False
        endTime = Timer

        Sheet4.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = endTime - startTime 'Execution time in miliseconds
    Next

    Sheet4.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: This answer explains everything in detail while being easy to understand. To show my gratitude to this excellent answer, I've added a 100 point bounty which will be applied as soon as possible. (Bounties are locked for 24 hours)

Comment: I'm not sure your benchmark is valid - when I run this code I get an almost perfectly even distribution of results for the 25 iterations with about half of the runs taking longer with each method. The `Timer` function also returns seconds, not milliseconds ;-).

Comment: Very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII 1 is 'SOH' (Start of Heading), and ASCII 2 'STX' meant the end of the header, start of the data stream. (This allows you to 'hide' addresses, notes, whatever, in a file ahead of the actual data in the file.)  It looks like Excel is interpreting your command to start at the beginning of the file and include everything.

Comment: AFAIK excel checks the strings inside the cells directly (not the data as a whole). While this includes the formatting, it ignores the structure (so you cannot corrupt the file).

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer. 
How i found.
I typed "Alt+1" (1 from num pad) then i got this "?" (question mark).
Now i typed below code, which clears the sheet.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace "?", "", xlPart, , True, , False, False
```

Comment: `Chr(1)` returns SOH which can be proven. So that's not the reason sorry :(

Comment: I tried in Excel, Alt+1 gives me a smiling face but in VBA immediate window, it gives Question mark ! However, Alt + 2, Alt+3, Alt+4 and so on --> all of them shows question mark in the Immediate VBA window and they do not clear the worksheet. So, you tried well but unfortunately, that's not correct solution.

Answer (score -3):

ASCII 1, as identified by many people, it interpreted by applications as start of heading for each characters. However, special characters can be escaped by some other characters ('~' is escape character in Excel) [check here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/214138/how-to-find-and-replace-tildes-and-wildcard-characters-in-excel)

I believe, you should avoid replacing by chr(1) in your code.